# Retrieve different info from db into single view in ASP.NET MVC when respective link is clicked,

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to display different cat breed info in a single view whenever the respective link is clicked.
[image]

Like when I click "Find out more!" I should be retrieving info about that particular cat from db.

Here is how my controller looks like

```
{
        using (catbreedEntities db = new catbreedEntities())
        {
            var model = db.cats_front_page.Find(1);
            return View(model);

        }
    }
```

And here is how view looks like:

```
    @model royalcatbreed.Models.cats_front_page
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "BreedView";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h4 class="card-title">@Model.cat_name</h4>
```

I understand that with this I will only be able to retrieve the name of the first cat from db each time I click on "Find out more!". So, how can I retrieve data for each particular cat?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you look at any ASP.NET MVC tutorials related to routing? Those tutorials will describe how to add a parameter to a URL, and define your route so that it will accept that parameter and map it to one of the parameters of your action method, which you can then pass to your DB layer in order to retrieve a specific entity. That would allow you to pass the ID of each cat via the URL.

Comment: I'm quite new to ASP.NET MVC. Could you please provide more details?

Comment: I understand you're new - but you still can look up documentation and try to read it, and ask a specific question about it if you're unsure about it. Did you look at any ASP.NET MVC tutorials related to routing?

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me, Yes, I did. It's mostly about passing parameters to URL. I need to understand what I'm going to do beyond that. Like do I have to create a separate ActionResult for each cat?

Comment: No. Your action method would take a parameter, just like any method. By defining your route properly, the framework can map a value in the URL to a parameter of your action method. The documentation should explain all of this.

Comment: May I know which documentation are you referring to? Could you please send a link, if possible?

Comment: All you have to do is Google related things, like "asp.net mvc 5 routing" and you'll come across stuff like [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/).